# Не сохраняет данные в БД. Save и Update возвращают false

Tags: php, yii

Не могу понять, в чем проблема. Возможно, где-то какой-то косяк, но не могу понять в чем.

Не сохраняется запись в модели. Вот код контроллера:
http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/0we-xqf

**P.S.**  Пожалуйста, простите, если вопрос слишком прост.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Судя по коду:

```
if ($this->_model->validate()) {
    if ($this->_model->save() === false)
      throw new Exception("Ошибка!");
```

проблему нужно искать в `beforeSave()`.

То-есть, если валидация проходит без ошибок, но `save() === false`, то остается только метод `beforeSave()`, где через `return false` можно не дать сделать запись в БД.

Answer (score 2):

Кто вообще так пишет?

```
 if ($this->_model->save() === false)
```

Почему не написать

```
if (!$this->_model->save())
 echo "<pre>";
  var_dump($this->_model->errors()); // вроде так. И посмотри на ошибки
 echo "<pre>";
```

+ ко всему есть такое непонятное

```
if (isset($_POST['ajax']) && $_POST['ajax'] === 'create-page') {
      echo CActiveForm::validate($this->_model);
      Yii::app()->end();
    }
```

Зачем стоит **Yii::app()->end();**

Зачем писать так

```
 private $_model = null;
```

Просто

```
 private $_model;
```

Зачем переписывать то что сгенерил тебе gii, не нужно пытаться сделать лучше, если оно не нужно здесь.

```
 if ($this->_model->save() === false)
          throw new Exception("Ошибка!");
```

Да, везде пихай

```
throw new Exception
```

Чтобы всем было понятно для чего оно там нужно!

Напиши проще код убери лишнее, выведи себе все по шагам.

Comment: Многое из того, что вы раскритиковали я взял из официальной документации. Вам спасибо большое.

Answer (score 1):

Раз валидацию вы проходите выше - пропробуйте

```
$this->_model->save(false);
```